# Optocoupler / 5 V, 1 A DC

Tags: opto-isolator

I am looking for an optocoupler capable of handling 5 V, 1 A DC continuously, in SMD format. I must be doing it wrong or I don't know how to search properly, but I can't find any reference. Do you have any?

Comment: Welcome! Why do you need 1 A? Please draw a schematic.

Comment: Hi! As it is currently asked, you seem to be requesting a product recommedation, and that would mean this question would be closed as off-topic, as these are specifically not in the scope of this website. I fully agree with winny: it's not usually the job of an octocoupler to provide a large current. You would hence need some means to amplify the current. But how you do that depends on what speeds, currents, voltages, loads, and so on we're talking about. I'm afraid without understanding *what* you do, and *why* you need that octocoupler, we'll be unable to help. A schematic is a good way!

Comment: It makes no sense as you can use any optocoupler and any transistor that can handle 5V and 1A to build a circuit that can do what you want, instead of requiring an optocoupler to do it directly. Also parts that you seek may not be named optocouplers, they might be called e.g. solid state relays.

Comment: No circuit to propose for the moment. I'm imagining one at the moment. The optocoupler would indeed not be the right track. Thanks for the feedback. I'll share later if I come up with something convincing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Is this part close enough? (Available in THT pinned dip and SMD flush bent pins)  https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1524131.pdf
(Unfortunately this part does need a higher load voltage.)

This family may be a better fit:
(Summary sheet claims 0V ~ 40V load voltage, and a 2A load current.)
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G3VM-41DY1/5799780

Comment: Wrong. It will **not** work at 5V. And got even accepted as an answer.

Comment: You're right. I accepted to stop this discussion. Wrong way by this channel. My bad.

Comment: @hervema - Note edits in original answer.  Also, there are few small opto-coupler parts as the load current reaches or exceeds 500ma. The idea of using a lower current part (and likely at a lower cost), then adding a 1A transistor to handle the higher current is a viable solution too.